# Parameter validation

Tags: powershell, validateset

Im trying to validate a parameter called "Collect" to accept only 3 parameters (basic, medium and full) but when i asign a "valid" value to the "collect" parameter, it got a "false" return.

**Thats what i did:**

```
[CmdLetBinding()]
param([string]$Collect)
)

if ($collect -ne ('basic' -or 'medium' -or 'full')) {
  Write-Host "'collect' is mandatory with mandatory values. For reference, use -help argument" -ForegroundColor Red
  exit
}
```

**Running test:**

c:\script.ps1 -collect basic

```
'collect' is mandatory with mandatory values. For reference, use -help argument
```

**PD**:
-I know that i could use validateset, but this dont work for me.
-I think the problem is in the nested $collect -ne ('basic' -or 'medium' -or 'full'), but how can i solve it?

Comment: [1] you cannot chain logical operators like that.  >>> `($collect -ne ('basic' -or 'medium' -or 'full'))` <<< the structure is simply not valid. try it out on its own. [*grin*] ///// [2] PoSh has validation methods - take a look at the following ... Simplify Your PowerShell Script with Parameter Validation | Scripting Blog — https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/simplify-your-powershell-script-with-parameter-validation/

Comment: Why not just use the `ValidateSet` attribute? `[ValidateSet('basic','medium','full')]`

Comment: "I know that i could use validateset, but this dont work for me. " <- why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `-or` operation *always* evaluates to a `[bool]` - so your `if` condition is basically `$collect -ne $true`.

You'll want to use `-notin` instead of `-ne`:

```
if($collect -notin 'basic','medium','full'){ 
   # ...
}
```

Or better yet, just use a `ValidateSet` attribute:

```
param(
  [ValidateSet('basic','medium','full')]
  [string]$Collect
)
```

Comment: The problem with Validateset is that if i stablish a -help parameter 
(example: 
[switch]$help;
if ($help){write-host "help output"})
-help does not work alone without -collect too

Comment: @Richard The solution to that is to NOT attempt to reinvent the wheel by defining your own custom `-help` parameter :-)

Comment: I'm just starting to learn powershell. So do you mean there's a default "-help" parameter that i can use? Any example or reference?

Comment: @Richard Yes. It's `-?`, not `-help`. Like, `.\path\to\yourScript.ps1 -?`